# How to include wx in my c++ code (MSVS 2019)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, wxwidgets, wxformbuilder

I want to include the wx library in my c++ program but following the given default instruction don't include the library in Visual Studio 2019

I tried (quoting from the instruction `install.md`):

1. Open a "Visual Studio Command Prompt"
2. Change directory to \%WXWIN\%\build\msw and type

   ```
   > nmake /f makefile.vc
   ```

Also i tried to include the file `wxwidgets.props` as explained in the given instruction

If i try to do

```cpp
#include <wx/frame.h>
```

is marked as mistake ("impossible to open "wx/frame.h" of origin file)

Note: for the creation of the GUI I'm also using wxFormBuilder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time wondering around forum, I've found a video on Youtube explaining how to include wx in your Visual Studio project, so i decided to post the answer to my question helping how will need this help in the future like i needed.

1. First of all you need to open in the Wx Directory and go to `wxWidgets-X.X.X\build\msw` and open with Visual Studio `wx_vc15.sln` (or more recent if available)
2. Compiling the solution in `Debug`, `DebugDLL`, `Relase` and `RelaseDLL`.
3. Now open your project (new or old) and open the `Project` menu and tap `Project propriety`
4. Select configuration `All configuration`, go to section C/C++ and in `Additional Include directorys` add `\wxWidgets-X.X.X\include`
5. Next go under Preprocessor and add in `Processor definition` the string `WXUSINGDLL`
6. Go under `Linker` and on `Additional library Directory` add `\wxWidgets-X.X.X\lib\vc_dll`
7. Change configuration to debug and under `C\C++` add another additional include directory that is `wxWidgets-X.X.X\lib\vc_dll\mswud`
8. Finally, as step 7, change to relase and add `wxWidgets-X.X.X\lib\vc_dll\mswu`

This will include the wx library in your code

Here the link for the video  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EI2taYkErRg  if you need more detail or if you need visually the explaination.

NOTE: in the `install.md` is missing the part of including the library in the project in this way, it mention only to compile the Debug version not well explaining why or what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

It's generally a good idea to read documentation when trying to use new software. In this case, the relevant documentation is in the file [docs/msw/install.md](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/v3.1.2/docs/msw/install.md) (or `install.txt` in earlier wxWidgets versions) and its "Building Applications Using wxWidgets" section contains the information that you need.

Comment: Is still not working. I've did as in the install.md/txt is specified for MSVS (adding the `wxwidgets.props`) and still no wx library is recognized ( same error as the question)

Comment: This really should work, please check that `AdditionalIncludeDirectories` option contains the entries defined in `wxwidgets.props`.